# ActionView::SyntaxErrorInTemplate in ArticlesController#edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[syntax template error while running in localhost]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wK60.png

[new.html.erb code]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SynF6.png

[edit.html.erb code]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/stMGv.png

[show.html.erb code]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8dUJ.png

[form.html.erb code]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZL46S.png

I copied everything verbatim per the instructions in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html.  I even recopied everything line-by-line...no luck.

Any suggestions/advice on how to deal with this issue would be amazing.

Thank you

Comment: i'll add that link to the original post

Answer (score 0):

Looks like problem with opened / closed `div`s

You need to close `div` that contains `body` attribute input

```
<div>
  <%= form.label :body %><br>
  <%= form.text_area :body %><br>
  <% article.errors.full_messages_for(:body).each do |message| %>
    <div><%= message %></div>
  <% end %>
</div> <!-- this one -->
```

And also use `<%=` instead of `<% =`

Comment: Wow, backspacing <%= worked.  I can now edit posts without any issue.  Thank you